# Python/Selenium code to open an application and login ( GUI Automation)

Tags: python, selenium, user-interface, autoit

Am working on a project where i need to gather information from different websites ( Internal to company) and also few information from an windows  application developed in Java.

I was able to pull all the information from websites using Selenium/Python, now I have an Window application where i need to fetch some information. Since selenium is not supporting Window application am not able to continue with that. I tried using AutoIt but my application is developed on JAVA and autoit windows spy is not able to detect many buttons on the application.

Any suggestion/Idea based on your experience how to proceed further ?
I have 80% of my information in websites which I have already scripted to pull only pending is this applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Java application is using DB (it almost certainly does) you can try getting the data from there directly instead of extracting it from the GUI.

Comment: Yes that can be done but getting access to that DB might be bit challenging

Comment: You'd better take that one-time challendge of saving your self from all the troubles that will certainly arise when the app UI changes and you're asked to extract additional info.